# ValidateAntiForgeryToken Filter is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, model-view-controller, action-filter

I have created two projects lets say projectA and projectB.

Now in projectA I have created the following action method.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Index(Employee employee)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

And, this action method has a view Index.cshtml which has a form and

> @Html.AntiForgeryToken() in form tag.

Now in projectB I have created an action method and a view.

This view has a form with action

> projectA/Home/Index

And,

> @Html.AntiForgeryToken() helper.

Now the problem is, When I submit the form from projectB, It hits the action methid of projectA.

Why is this happening? What am I missing here?

Comment: You projects are website? if thier are `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` validationData will save in website self.

Comment: Yes both the projects are in asp.net mvc 5. But its not working as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Token generation and validation in recent .Net is relatively complex. It is based on the cookie being compared to the posted value, but not so simple, these two are not identical.

`System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.TokenValidator` compares `SecurityToken` in `AntiForgeryToken`. However, it is all encrypted, and also contains other fields like for example the username. If you are running on the same machine, with the same encryption key, and on the same domain, it would still work though. However, the cookie name also has the application path encoded. So when you post from one application to the other, the cookie name won't match, and validation will not work.

One solution to this is to set `AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName` to the same value. While it will work with applications on the same machine (with the same key), and the same domain, I don't think this is good practice, because it won't work in any other scenario. You can set the key to the same on different computers (which is already not good practice security-wise), but cookies will not be sent to different domains.

Comment: Dear Gabor, I am not using any encryption key as Salt is deprecated from ValidateAntiForgeryToken. Also Validate token also create unique key per session. So I don't think it is right to say that it won't work on the same local machine.

Comment: Also, Value of __RequestVerificationToken for both the form is different.